# Simple woocommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, cart, checkout

I want to make the woocommerce checkout page as simple as like attached image.

[image: Checkout page]

Payment method and cart section only, no customer details section.

How can customize the checkout page like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the WooCommerce templates by copying them over to your child theme directory under the path `child-theme/woocommerce/checkout`.  The main file is called `form-checkout.php`

Comment: child-theme/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php
would you please confirm the path again?
which one is correct?

Comment: You don't include the directory templates  => "child-theme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php"

Comment: perfect! works fine, very helpful
I was tried with another path, but it doesn't work.
 could you tell me the reason why it doesn't work with another one that includes "templates/"?

Comment: Each template needs to go in the correct sub-directory.  What other template file are you trying to override?  Here's the official documentation https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: fully understood, you saved me today

Comment: sorry for delay, I just accept your answer, It was a really great help.